# launching two app in iphone sdk?

Tags: iphone, ipad, iphone-sdk-3.0

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Launch an app from within another (iPhone)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419119/launch-an-app-from-within-another-iphone)

i want to launch another Application in iphone sdk...for example the user has downloaded two application from appstore.when he touch the button which is in one APplication, Another Application must be opened, current one must be closed..is it Possible?

Comment: @Paul Alexander It is interesting to notice that all answer that has been provided and which is also right have been down voted... with possible reason to take revenge of down voting wrong answer (which has been deleted )

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure the only way you can do this is if the second application registers itself as a handler for some DocumentType, and then the first application handles such a document. The user will be prompted to open the document with the second application. You can read more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4517092/how-does-open-with-some-app-in-iphone-work).

You can't just launch applications on behalf of the user, though.

Answer (score 0):

You can register a custom URL Scheme in your Application B, and then open it from your Application A using this custom URL Scheme.

More info [here](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/cocoa/launching-your-own-application-via-a-custom-url-scheme.html)

Answer (score 0):

If the target application has a registered custom url scheme, you can use that to open the other app.

http://iosdevelopertips.com/cocoa/launching-your-own-application-via-a-custom-url-scheme.html